# What is a good word to descibe someone who refers to you as the expert in a sarcastic way

Tags: single-word-requests

Background:

My job description is subject matter expert for a particular business topic.  This person is a manager in same field but at a high level, not process and procedures.  My expertise has to do with complex regulations.

I answered an employee question with an incorrect answer once and he's never let me forget it.  Now whenever someone tells him to come and ask me something particular, he makes comments like "Yes let's ask _ _ _ _ _ she's the expert." I've overheard him more than once and sometimes will add to the phrase by saying "on everything."

I only offer information when asked.  I don't push it on anyone, and am sensitive of being perceived as a know it all.  I guess this is why it bothers me.  I'd like speak to him about this but looking for that one word that describes how I perceive his remarks.

Comment: Words like "jerk", "jackass", "twit", and so forth come to mind.  You should chat with your HR rep about his demeaning behavior.

Comment: You don't have an English problem; you have a workplace problem.  See http://workplace.stackexchange.com/  I suggest you delete your question here and rephrase it for The Workplace.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would call it "derisive praise," where _derisive_ means (according to Merriam-Webster) "expressing or causing derision ['the use of ridicule or scorn  to show contempt']."

Comment: @ab2 this really isn't a good fit for Workplace as it's a question asking for a specific word. And not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: Derisive. Example reply. Using humour, timing, and wit can take the wind from his sails. 'Yes! You're so right! I am indeed the general factotum around here! I find your comments a little derisive though - would you mind?' ...pause...  ...smile... ...keep smiling...  allow his response... Then say 'now, what was your question? Can we get on?' Practise it in the mirror, until the words roll gracefully from your tongue unbidden. Then role-play it with a friend until it makes you both roll around laughing. Then try doing it.  Agree and puff them up first, then gently burst the balloon.

Answer (score 3):

I think "condescending" would be an apt description.

Or really, "unfair" might work too, as it is pretty unfair he'd give you so much trouble over one mistake, when I assume your advice is typically helpful.

EDIT: Also, I think the word you used yourself, "sarcastic", is an equally good word, if not better! Because that's exactly what his remarks are. Keep in mind to be careful he isn't just joking; there may be no bad intentions, and it's entirely possible he doesn't understand his teasing is bothering you. :)